# MySQL query over 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having a few problems creating a SQL Query.

I have the following tables:

```
**Tour**
tourID
tourName

**Schedule**
scheduleID
tourID

**Ticket**
scheduleID
customerID
```

And what I want to select is the `tourname` and the number of tickets sold per tour. I know how to select the number of tickets sold by schedule but I'm stuck getting it linked to the tour.

Number of tickets per schedule:

```
SELECT t.scheduleID, COUNT(t.scheduleID) AS numTickets
FROM Ticket t
GROUP BY t.scheduleID
```

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select t.tourname, COUNT(tc.scheduleID) AS numTickets
From Tour t 
inner join Schedule s on t.tourID = s.tourID
inner join Ticket   tc on s.scheduleID = tc.scheduleID
group by t.tourID, t.tourname
```